# Border onTap over container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

About a couple of days into flutter, but I can't figure how to add a border `onTap` to a `Container` that's wrapped in `InkWell` that is `pageController` (there are few in a row). I want my Container to have white border when tapped/selected, but for the love of god can't figure how.
Would appreciate any help/explanation, so I can learn from this.

Like on image below, when I tap on either of those the selected item has border around it

**White Border upon onTap**

[image: White Border upon onTap]

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SinglePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SinglePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SinglePage createState() => _SinglePage();
}

class _SinglePage extends State<SinglePage> {
  late PageController pageViewController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageViewController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF090F13),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        title: const Text(
          'FIRST',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 32,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        actions: const [],
        centerTitle: false,
        elevation: 2,
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF262D34),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 0, 0, 25),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        Material(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          elevation: 3,
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: 150,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color(0xFF090F13),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: Image.asset(
                                  'assets/images/first.jpg',
                                ).image,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 12, 20, 0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            'Choose role',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                              color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 12, 1, 0),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                  16, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  await pageViewController.animateToPage(
                                    0,
                                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                    curve: Curves.ease,
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Material(
                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                  elevation: 2,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  ),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 100,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: const Color(0xFF090F13),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                        border:
                                            Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(
                                              0, -0.05),
                                          child: Column(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              Image.asset(
                                                'assets/images/icon-position.png',
                                                width: 50,
                                                height: 50,
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              ),
                                              const Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                    .fromSTEB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                                                child: AutoSizeText(
                                                  'text',
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                                                    color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.normal,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                  16, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Material(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                elevation: 2,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                ),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 100,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: const Color(0xFF090F13),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  ),
                                  child: InkWell(
                                    onTap: () async {
                                      await pageViewController.animateToPage(
                                        1,
                                        duration:
                                            const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                        curve: Curves.ease,
                                      );
                                    },
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(
                                              0, -0.05),
                                          child: Column(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              Image.asset(
                                                'assets/images/icon-position.png',
                                                width: 50,
                                                height: 50,
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              ),
                                              const Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                    .fromSTEB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                                                child: AutoSizeText(
                                                  'SECOND',
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                                                    color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.normal,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 8, 20, 8),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            'SinglePage',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                              color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                16, 8, 16, 0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              height: 200,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0x00090F13),
                                boxShadow: const [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    blurRadius: 3,
                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                                  )
                                ],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: 500,
                                child: PageView(
                                  controller: pageViewController,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'assets/images/first.png',
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    ),
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'assets/images/second.png',
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 0, 20, 8),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: const [
                  AutoSizeText(
                    'Text',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include more of your code? The closing parameters are not correct in your snippet and it would be great if you can fix those as well so I can run your code.

Comment: We have several ways to do so can you please explain you purpose?

Comment: updated with a code and a picture

Comment: You need to select one of them at a time right?

Comment: that's right, only one, it's basically a switch I just need to indicate which one is pressed at the moment

Comment: one more thing there will be only two fields or they are dynamic can be increase ?

Comment: just two fields, no dynamic inc

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define two veriable  `bool isFirtButton = false` and `bool isSecondButton = false`

and set border based on condition: First button border `border:isFirtButton ? Border.all(color: Colors.white) : null)`, second button border  `border:isSecondButton ? Border.all(color: Colors.white) : null`

Here Full code:

```
class SinglePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SinglePage({Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SinglePage createState() => _SinglePage();
}

class _SinglePage extends State<SinglePage> {
  PageController pageViewController;
  bool isFirtButton = false;
  bool isSecondButton = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageViewController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF090F13),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        title: const Text(
          'FIRST',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 32,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        actions: const [],
        centerTitle: false,
        elevation: 2,
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF262D34),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 0, 0, 25),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        Material(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          elevation: 3,
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: 150,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color(0xFF090F13),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: Image.asset(
                                  'assets/images/first.jpg',
                                ).image,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 12, 20, 0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            'Choose role',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                              color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 12, 1, 0),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                  16, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  isSecondButton = false;
                                  isFirtButton = true;
                                  setState(() {});
                                  await pageViewController.animateToPage(
                                    0,
                                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                    curve: Curves.ease,
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Material(
                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                  elevation: 2,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  ),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 100,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: const Color(0xFF090F13),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                        border:
                                            isFirtButton ? Border.all(color: Colors.white) : null),
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(
                                              0, -0.05),
                                          child: Column(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              Image.asset(
                                                'assets/images/icon-position.png',
                                                width: 50,
                                                height: 50,
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              ),
                                              const Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                    .fromSTEB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  'text',
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                                                    color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.normal,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                  16, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Material(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                elevation: 2,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                ),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 100,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: const Color(0xFF090F13),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                    border:isSecondButton ? Border.all(color: Colors.white) : null
                                  ),
                                  child: InkWell(
                                    onTap: ()async  {
                                      isSecondButton = true;
                                      isFirtButton = false;
                                      setState(() {});
                                      await pageViewController.animateToPage(
                                        1,
                                        duration:
                                            const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                        curve: Curves.ease,
                                      );
                                    },
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(
                                              0, -0.05),
                                          child: Column(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              Image.asset(
                                                'assets/images/icon-position.png',
                                                width: 50,
                                                height: 50,
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              ),
                                              const Padding(
                                                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional
                                                    .fromSTEB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  'SECOND',
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                                                    color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.normal,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 8, 20, 8),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            'SinglePage',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Lexend Deca',
                              color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                16, 8, 16, 0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              height: 200,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0x00090F13),
                                boxShadow: const [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    blurRadius: 3,
                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                                  )
                                ],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: 500,
                                child: PageView(
                                  controller: pageViewController,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'assets/images/first.png',
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    ),
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'assets/images/second.png',
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 0, 20, 8),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: const [
                  Text(
                    'Text',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      color: Color(0xFF8B97A2),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly mate, and it's really simple, tried Lists as well and they work but I think yours is the simplest, cheers !

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing it, using a `bool` to hold the state of click event.

```dart
 bool enableBorder = false; // on state class

 ///... on inkWell
 onTap: () => setState(() => enableBorder = !enableBorder)
```

For your case, just use

`border: enableBorder ? Border.all(color: Colors.white) : null,`

**Update for List**

```dart
List<int> selectionItems = [];
 ///
borderRadius:
    selectionItems.contains(0) ? BorderRadius.circular(28) : null,
onTap: () => setState(() {
  selectionItems.contains(0)
      ? selectionItems.remove(0)
      : selectionItems.add(0);
}),
```

and use

```dart
 border: selectionItems.contains(0)
                  ? Border.all(color: Colors.white)
                  : null,
```

Comment: Ok that's some progress, but the problem is it draws a border onTap on 1 item but when I select other item the other border does not disappear and now I have 2 of them. Any clue how you can do it so when I switch from first to 2nd item, border disappears from previous chosen and shows only on 1 of those ?

Comment: for this you need to use `List<int> selectedItemIndex = []` and add them while selection

Comment: I am just curious to know what was issue with this approach, where you will end up creating nth variable for this, you can think about selected items on list, that's why i showed this way :)

Comment: Oh sorry, still it marks 2 borders onTap instead of 1

Comment: try with changing index for next one ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below as reference you can customize as per your need :

create a **List** of `bool` like this :

```
List<bool> list = [false, false];
```

and paste this to your `code`

```
Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() {
                      list[0] = true;
                      list[1] = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Card(
                    color: list[0] ? Colors.blue : null,
                    child: Text("1st Container"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() {
                      list[1] = true;
                      list[0] = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Card(
                    color: list[1] ? Colors.blue : null,
                    child: Text("2nd Container"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
```